# MONOTOUCH open a viewcontroller on tableview cell is clicked

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I Have the following viewcontroller with a tableview and a custom cell:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using Mono.Data.Sqlite;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Zurfers.Mobile.Core;
using AlexTouch.MBProgressHUD;
using System.Collections;

namespace Zurfers.Mobile.iOS
{
    public partial class iPhoneHotelSearchViewController : UIViewController
    {

        MBProgressHUD hud;

        public string Destination {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public DateTime CheckInDate {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public DateTime CheckOutDate {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public int Rooms {
            get;
            set;
        }   

        public iPhoneHotelSearchViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {

        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            hud = new MBProgressHUD(this.View);
            hud.Mode = MBProgressHUDMode.Indeterminate;
            hud.LabelText = "Loading...";
            hud.DetailsLabelText = "Searching Hotel";
            this.View.AddSubview(hud);
            hud.Show(true);

        }

        public override void ViewDidAppear (bool animated) {
            base.ViewDidAppear (animated);
            SearchHotel ();

        }

        public void SearchHotel (){

            Hotel hotel = new Hotel();
            var distribution = new HotelDistribution[]{new HotelDistribution(){ Adults = 1, Children = 0, ChildrenAges = new int[0]} };
            var items = hotel.SearchHotels(Convert.ToDateTime("2013-08-08"),Convert.ToDateTime("2013-09-09 "),"(MIA)", distribution,"","","",0);


            List<DtoHotelinformation> data = new List<DtoHotelinformation>();

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                DtoHotelinformation DtoHotelinformation = new DtoHotelinformation();
                DtoHotelinformation.code  = item.Code.ToString();
                DtoHotelinformation.price  = item.Price.ToString();
                DtoHotelinformation.title =  item.Name.ToString().ToTitleCase();
                DtoHotelinformation.subtitle = item.Address.ToString();
                DtoHotelinformation.rating  = item.Rating.ToString();
                DtoHotelinformation.imageUlr = item.ImageUrl;

                data.Add(DtoHotelinformation);
            }

            hud.Hide(true);
            hud.RemoveFromSuperview();
            HotelSearchTable.Source = new HotelTableSource(data.ToArray());
            HotelSearchTable.ReloadData();

        }

        partial void GoBack (MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject sender)
        {
            DismissViewController(true, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the table source

```
using System;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace Zurfers.Mobile.iOS
{
    public class HotelTableSource : UITableViewSource
    {

        DtoHotelinformation[] tableItems;
        NSString cellIdentifier = new NSString("TableCell");



        public HotelTableSource (DtoHotelinformation[] items)
        {
            tableItems = items;
        }
        public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, int section)
        {
            return tableItems.Length;
        }

        public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            //WHAT TO DO HERE

            tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true); // normal iOS behaviour is to remove the blue highlight
        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            CustomCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellIdentifier) as CustomCell;

            if (cell == null)
                cell = new CustomCell(cellIdentifier);
            cell.UpdateCell(tableItems[indexPath.Row].title, tableItems[indexPath.Row].subtitle, tableItems[indexPath.Row].price,
                            tableItems[indexPath.Row].imageUlr, tableItems[indexPath.Row].rating );
            return cell;

        }

        public override float GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            return 70;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally the customcell code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using MonoTouch.Dialog.Utilities;

namespace Zurfers.Mobile.iOS
{
    public class CustomCell : UITableViewCell, IImageUpdated
    {
        UILabel headingLabel, subheadingLabel, priceLabel;
        UIImageView imageService;
        UIImageView star, star2, star3, star4, star5;
        public CustomCell (NSString cellId) : base (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellId)
        {
            imageService = new UIImageView();
            star   = new UIImageView();
            star2  = new UIImageView();
            star3  = new UIImageView();
            star4  = new UIImageView();
            star5  = new UIImageView();
            headingLabel = new UILabel(){
                Font = UIFont.FromName("Verdana-Bold", 14f),
                BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear,
                TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB(241, 241, 211)
            };
            subheadingLabel = new UILabel(){
                Font = UIFont.FromName("Verdana-Bold", 8f),
                TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB(255, 255, 255),
                BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear
            };
            priceLabel = new UILabel(){
                Font = UIFont.FromName("Verdana", 14f),
                TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB(241, 241, 211),
                BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear
            };

            AddSubview(imageService);
            AddSubview(headingLabel);
            AddSubview(subheadingLabel);
            AddSubview(priceLabel);
            AddSubview(star);
            AddSubview(star2);
            AddSubview(star3);
            AddSubview(star4);
            AddSubview(star5);

        }

        public void UpdateCell (string title, string subtitle, string price, string imageUlr, string rating )
        {
            if (imageUlr != null) {
                var u = new Uri(imageUlr);
                ImageLoader MyLoader= new ImageLoader(50,50);
                imageService.Image = MyLoader.RequestImage(u,this);

            } else {
                imageService.Image = UIImage.FromFile("generic_no_image_tiny.jpg");
            }


            headingLabel.Text = title;
            subheadingLabel.Text = subtitle;
            if (subtitle.Length > 40) {
                subheadingLabel.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
                subheadingLabel.Lines = 0;
            }

            switch (rating) {
                case "T":
                    star.Image = UIImage.FromFile("ZurfersMovil-Stars.png");
                    star2.Image = UIImage.FromFile("ZurfersMovil-Stars.png");
                    break;
                case "S":
                    star.Image = UIImage.FromFile("ZurfersMovil-Stars.png");
                    star2.Image = UIImage.FromFile("ZurfersMovil-Stars.png");
                    star3.Image = UIImage.FromFile("ZurfersMovil-Stars.png");
                    break;
                case "F":
                    star.Image = UIImage.FromFile("ZurfersMovil-Stars.png");
                    star2.Image = UIImage.FromFile("ZurfersMovil-Stars.png");
                    star3.Image = UIImage.FromFile("ZurfersMovil-Stars.png");
                    star4.Image = UIImage.FromFile("ZurfersMovil-Stars.png");
                    break;
                case "L":
                    star.Image = UIImage.FromFile("ZurfersMovil-Stars.png");
                    star2.Image = UIImage.FromFile("ZurfersMovil-Stars.png");
                    star3.Image = UIImage.FromFile("ZurfersMovil-Stars.png");
                    star4.Image = UIImage.FromFile("ZurfersMovil-Stars.png");
                    star5.Image = UIImage.FromFile("ZurfersMovil-Stars.png");
                    break;
            }


            priceLabel.Text = "USD " + price;
            priceLabel.Font = UIFont.BoldSystemFontOfSize (16);
        }


        public void UpdatedImage (Uri uri)
        {
            imageService.Image = ImageLoader.DefaultRequestImage(uri, this);
        }


        public override void LayoutSubviews ()
        {
            base.LayoutSubviews ();
            imageService.Frame = new RectangleF(10, 10, 50, 33);
            headingLabel.Frame = new RectangleF(70, 4, 240, 25);
            subheadingLabel.Frame = new RectangleF(70, 25, 240, 20);
            priceLabel.Frame = new RectangleF(220, 45, 100, 20);
            star.Frame = new RectangleF(70, 45, 15, 15);
            star2.Frame = new RectangleF(85, 45, 15, 15);
            star3.Frame = new RectangleF(100, 45, 15, 15);
            star4.Frame = new RectangleF(115, 45, 15, 15);
            star5.Frame = new RectangleF(130, 45, 15, 15);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to open another viewcontroller (iPhoneHotelDetailViewController) when the user touch a cell of the table view. But I don not have any idea of how to do this.

Could you help me please.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, you want a NavigationController to be the "top" element in your app, wrapping all the other controllers.

In your AppDelegate, create a NavigationController, and make it the root of your application.

Then create an instance of your Search controller and push it onto the NavigationController.

Finally, add a NavigationController property to the constructor of your TableSource.

```
NavigationController nav;

public HotelTableSource (DtoHotelinformation[] items, NavigationController nav)
{
   this.nav = nav;
   tableItems = items;
}
```

When you create your TableSource, pass the NavigationController reference in.  You can do this because all ViewControllers have a property that points to their NavigationController, if they are contained within one.

```
HotelSearchTable.Source = new HotelTableSource(data.ToArray(), this.NavigationController);
```

Finally, in your RowSelected, create an instance of the new ViewController you want to display:

```
    public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        //WHAT TO DO HERE
        MyDetailController myDetail = new MyDetailController();
        nav.PushViewController(myDetail, true);

        tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true); // normal iOS behaviour is to remove the blue highlight
    }
```

Comment: Could I show another viewcontroller without a navigationcontroller??

Comment: Yes, every ViewController has a PresentViewController and PresentModalViewController method you can also use without a Navigation controller

Comment: Jason, that does not work. I don't have an constructor with out params and if I add a constructor with out parameters, I get a  System.NullReferencesException, also I don't have a navigation controller. THis is my code:

UINavigationController controller = new UINavigationController();
   iPhoneHotelDetailViewController myDetail = new iPhoneHotelDetailViewController();
   controller.NavigationController.PushViewController(myDetail, true);

   tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true);

Comment: if you post a complete code sample on the Xamarin forums I'll take a look at it - SO is not a good format for an extended back-and-forth like this

Answer (score 2):

I think that link to `UINavigationController` (UI component) in `UITableViewSource` is a bit weird. I recommend to use event-based approach:

- Declare event in `UITableViewSource` and call it on row selection:

```cs
public event Action<int> OnRowSelect;
...
public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true); // normal iOS behaviour is to remove the blue highlight

    if (OnRowSelect != null) {
        OnRowSelect(indexPath.Row);
    }
}
```

- Then, handle event on `UIViewController` - push new `UIViewController`:

```cs
var source = data.ToArray();
source.OnRowSelect += HandleOnRowSelect;
HotelSearchTable.Source = new HotelTableSource();
HotelSearchTable.ReloadData();
...
void HandleOnRowSelect(int index)
{
    var data = items[index];

    // Pass data to new view controller and push it
}
```

Tip to avoid memory leaks: don't forget to unsubscribe from OnRowSelect when you `Pop` this `UIViewController` or making new `UITableViewSource` instance. I.e:

- Declare `source` in as class member;
- Unsubscribe from it's event in, for example, `ViewWillDisappear`:

```cs
source.OnRowSelect -= HandleOnRowSelect;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using StoryBord there is a very easy way to do this. You would then pass the data whit in the PrepareForSegue method like this.

```
public override void PrepareForSegue (UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
        {
            base.PrepareForSegue (segue, sender);

            NSIndexPath indexPatch = tableView.IndexPathForSelectedRow;

            if (segue.Identifier.Equals ("showHotelDetail")) {

                    var vc = segue.DestinationViewController as iPhoneHotelDetailViewController;
                    if (vc != null) {

                        //Pass some date to the iPhoneHotelDetailViewController if needed.
                        vc.hotelName = this.tableItems [indexPatch.Row].hotelName;

                    }
            }
        }
```

In your StoryBoard connect the customCell with the iPhoneHotelDetailViewController and call the segue "showHotelDetail" for example.